# Method on readonly field can modify the method outside of constructor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express with a C# project. I seem to remember this was not the case in prior versions of visual studio and am wondering if this is a bug.

In the code below Empty is a static readonly field but can be modified outside it's constructor with Empty.Clear()

```
    public struct Box
{
    public static readonly float D = float.MaxValue;
    public static readonly Box Empty = new Box(new Vector3(D, D, D), new Vector3(-D, -D, -D));

    public Vector3 Min;
    public Vector3 Max;

    public Box(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Min = new Vector3(D, D, D);
        Max = -Min;
        Empty.Clear(); // I seem to remember this should not be allowed
    }
}
```

Comment: well it is a reference type, so I'm not particularly surprised by this

Comment: yes, I believe the object can manipulate itself after being set, however the object itself can't be changed, for example, if it was a string and you try to do `x = "hello";` it would fail.

Comment: Calling a mutating method(but not a property setter) has always been allowed. But the compiler should insert a defensive copy, so the original field doesn't get changed - only the copy gets changed. Can you verify that the field gets changed? If yes, I'd consider that a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Your not actually modifying the field, your calling a method on the object.

Modifying it would be something like

```
Empty = null;
```

Comment: `Box` is a struct, so your argument doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `readonly` only states that the reference (in case of a reference type) to an instance can only be set by the constructor. The keyword `readonly` says nothing about what happens inside the instance.

In case of value types: `readonly` makes sure than onyl the constructor can set the value type, but it does not ensures that the value type itself cannot change its own values from within.